# Form submits on GET instead of POST occassionally

Tags: html

I have a form that has a hard coded method of POST. 99.8% of the time the form posts correctly and the access logs show that the user requested the page with the POST method. Is there anything that could cause the other .2% to click submit and the page request be made as a GET?

One user reported it happening multiple times in a row which has been corroborated by access logs.

It is happening on almost all browsers and across multiple operating systems for numerous users located at various places throughout the country.

Anyone know of malware or a virus that could cause behavior like this. Caching? Any pointers of where to look?

@Diodeus

```
<form id="someid" method="post" action="http://samepage?somevar=0" enctype="multipart/form-data" onkeypress="return check_enter(event);" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
  ... form elements ...
</form>
```

-

```
function check_enter(e) {
    var target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (keyCode==13 && target.nodeName.toLowerCase()!='a' &&
            (!target.type || !(target.type=='submit' || target.type=='textarea'))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: We're not psychic - include some code.

Comment: @Diodeus speak for your self.... ;)  99.8% im not a mathematician but how did you come up with ur statistics?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript in play?

Comment: Do some network analysis using Chrome/Chromiun's network inspector or Firefox's Firebug in order to see what page or script is doing the GET request.

Comment: That snippet is not enough. Can we see `check_enter`, for example?

Comment: @Nix i can check the access logs to see how many requests are for '%get%samepage%somevar=0%' vs '%post%samepage%somevar=0%' - there no way to get to the samepagesomvar=0 except through manual url entry or form submit

Comment: I'm having the same thing happen. Very frustrating. No pattern in terms of browser used.

Comment: I have forgotten about this since I left my previous job but I kinda remember we hypothesized that it was related to aggressive anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

I see the OP has since left the job. But It does sound like the gets were being generated by someone passing the variables in the URL querystring. We have this happen when the Security team slams our Redmine server and it generates a bunch of gets that are trying to create issues.